GCN link prediction negative sampling. If there is possible to sample potential y=1 samples?
When performing negative sampling in GCN for link prediction, what if you mistakenly sample potential links that are actually y=1 and treat them as negative samples? Would it be like forcing them to have no relationship?
The goal of link prediction is to identify the link relationships in the current network graph. If positive samples are y=1 (strongly related node pairs), and negative samples are y=0 (unrelated node pairs), the more precisely the model learns, the more similar the nodes in positive samples will become, and the more dissimilar the nodes in negative samples will become, to generate predictive values of 1 or 0.

However, negative sampling is conducted randomly, meaning samples are drawn from current seemingly non-existent (but potentially y=1 or y=0) link relationships and used as y=0 training data. What if such "potentially y=1" samples are mistakenly treated as negative? Would it be as if we are forcing them to have no relationship?

If so, how can a well-trained model effectively predict future links?
Currently, sampling is still conducted randomly.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
